# Combine two different dimensional arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two different dimensional arrays.

Array 1:

```
Array1 
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 123 
        [price] => 5
        [purchase_time] => 2014/4/10
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 123 
        [price] => 5
        [purchase_time] => 2014/5/17
    )
)
```

Array 2:

```
Array2 
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 8
)
```

I want something like this:

```
Array 
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 123 
        [price] => 5
        [purchase_time] => 2014/4/10
        [Qty] => 5
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 123 
        [price] => 5
        [purchase_time] => 2014/5/17
        [Qty] => 8
    )
)
```

Basically the first array is the information I got from a SQL table. The second array contains the quantity for the products sold. I now want to combine these two array together and use the combined array to create a new table. Since these two arrays have different dimensions. I'm not sure how to do it. Here is my try:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($array1 as $row)
{
    $newarray = array_merge($row,$array2[$i]);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: array_merge isn't going to magically create the `qty` key for you. That's something YOU'LL have to do, e.g. rename the key in the second array from 0->Qty

Comment: @MarcB Do you mean create something like this `$array2['Qty']`, and set the value of the array `$array2['Qty'][0] = 5`, `$array2['Qty'][1] = 8`?

Comment: no. that'd be backwards. `[0][qty]=5`

Answer (score 1):

Might be a simpler way, but for fun without `foreach`:

```
array_walk($array1, function(&$v, $k, $a){ $v['Qty'] = $a[$k]; }, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($array1 as &$row) {
    $row['Qty'] = $array2[$i++];
}
```

Or if keys of both arrays are the same (0,1,2...) and array have the same length:

```
foreach($array1 as $k => &$row) {
    $row['Qty'] = $array2[$k];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `$array1` and `$array2` are mapped by the same indexes, so they have same length, you can try:

```
foreach($array2 as $index=>$quantity){
  $array1[$index]['Qty'] = $quantity;
}
```

And it´s done!
If you want to keep the original `$array1` untouched, you can make a copy before the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Create new array and store it there. You can access the value of `$array2` because they have the same index of `$array1` so you can use the `$key` of these two arrays.

```
   $array3 = [];
   foreach($array1 as $key => $val) {
     $array3[] = [
       'id' => $val['id'],
       'price' => $val['price'],
       'purchase_time' => $val['purchase_time'],
       'Qty' => $array2[$key]
     ];
   }

  print_r($array3);
```